# Python & operator in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operators

I'm trying to combine these two parts as an AND statement.

```
dataframe = df.loc[~(df['Name'] < -1000)]
dataframe = df.loc[~(df['Name'] > 1000)]
```

I want it to do something like this:

```
dataframe = df.loc[~(df['Name'] < -1000)] & df.loc[~(df['Name'] > 1000)]
```

I have tried using **&** and **AND**, and both returned errors, need help.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, you don’t need to use `.loc`

```py
dataframe = df[~(df['Name'] < -1000) & ~(df['Name'] > 1000)]
```

Comment: @ShieldScrub if so please consider to mark this answer as accepted to close your question

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the ~

```
dataframe = df[df['Name'].between(-1000, 1000)]
```